# Cannot call overloaded methods of .NET API in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, overloading, overload-resolution, powershell-5.0

I have a 3rd party API that I want to use in a PowerShell script.  I can instantiate the objects and access properties and non-overloaded methods, but every call to an overloaded method fails with `Cannot find an overload for "<method>" and the argument count: "<count>".`

The API works fine when called from C#.

Example (here `$doc0` contains an instance of an object from the API and `Value` is the method I want to call):

```
PS C:\> $doc0.Value.OverloadDefinitions
System.Object IPSFNetDataItem.Value(int fieldIndex)
System.Object IPSFNetDataItem.Value(string field)

PS C:\> $doc0.FieldName(0) #Non-overloaded methods are ok.
ID

PS C:\> $doc0.Value([int]0) #overloaded methods fail
Cannot find an overload for "value" and the argument count: "1".
At line:1 char:1
+ $doc0.Value([int]0) #overloaded methods fail
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest


PS C:\> $doc0.Value([string]"why?") #overloaded methods fail
Cannot find an overload for "value" and the argument count: "1".
At line:1 char:1
+ $doc0.Value([string]"why?") #overloaded methods fail
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

I have looked at other similar questions (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538572/how-do-i-call-overloaded-static-methods-from-the-net-framework-in-powershell) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414618/powershell-cannot-find-overload)) but these solutions do not work in this case - there is surely no room for ambiguity in this very simple case and as the output from OverloadDefinitions shows, I am not trying to do anything that is not supported but the API.

I assume that PowerShell isn't usually *this* bad at resolving method calls; any ideas why this might be failing?

Comment: Does the issue stop if you remove the explicit type? e.g. `$doc0.Value("why?")` I'm not sure why your doing that but if you must you can wrap them in a subexpression. `$doc0.Value($([string]"why?"))` and it should work.

Comment: Makes no difference either way - still the same issue.  The explicit type was just to try and see if there was anything funny going on with type conversion.

Comment: Any chance you can share what 3rd party API you are using? I'd like to see if it is possible to get a copy and try tinkering with it.

Comment: It's PS Financials (PSFNetObjects.dll) v6.0.0.925.  I doubt if you'll be able to get one as AFAIK they don't licence or release the API separately from the rest of the software.